# Does the regular expression engine skip over strings that are shorter than the pattern?

Tags: .net, regex

I want to loop through a set of strings.  On each string i want to loop through a set of regular expression to determine which expressions match on the string I'm on.  However, If the string length is shorter than the maximum possible length of the pattern string, I want the regex engine to skip over it.

For example say I stop on a string "abc"
and test it with this regex.

```
(?i)[A-Z]{3}
```

and it matches.  Then my next expression to test is like

```
(?i)[A-Z]+(?=123)
```

Will the engine still start examining the string from the beginning even though the second case will never be a match?

If this is the case, is there a way to get it to skip over strings that don't meet minimum length requirement?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? `(?i)[A-Z]{3}` matches 3 Latin letter sequence, `(?i)[A-Z]+(?=123)` does the same but only those sequences that have no `123` right after. `123` is not a length restriction.

Comment: @stribizhev i was trying to improve performance by preventing the engine from examining strings that we know will never be a match because they aren't long enough.  If that is even possible

Comment: I'd say for such short strings the performance difference doesn't really matter. Especially with a compiled regex. You could also do the same with just a single match and look which group matched.

Comment: @Joey What about for longer strings with longer more complex patterns?

Comment: @erotavlas: For those complex patterns, it becomes rather hard to determine what the shortest valid input is.

Comment: Just do not tell me you parse XML/HTML with them.If yes, nothing will help but using appropriate parser.

Comment: @stribizhev no nothing like that :)

Comment: Ok, but again, when trying to improve performance, there should be performance trouble. Please provide a concrete case of performance degradation, and we'll be able to help. Right now, it sounds like off-topic.

Comment: @stribizhev well forget about the performance for a minute, my original question is still valid (i.e. is there a way to determine a length for a regular expression pattern in order to skip over strings shorter than that length) and it looks like the answer is no, or it would be very hard to determine.

Comment: You will need to reverse engineer regex library. If you have `*` or `+`, you can say that the length will be very long. It has been posted before, but I do not know how to find that post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're after implementation details, and when the source code is available, the best way to tell is to simply look at it. :)

The short answer is: *not exactly*.

The optimization implemented in the .NET regex implementation is a [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) string search as the first phase of matching **when possible**. Take a look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexBoyerMoore.cs) for the gory details.

From the code itself:

```
// The RegexBoyerMoore object precomputes the Boyer-Moore
// tables for fast string scanning. These tables allow
// you to scan for the first occurance of a string within
// a large body of text without examining every character.
// The performance of the heuristic depends on the actual
// string and the text being searched, but usually, the longer
// the string that is being searched for, the fewer characters
// need to be examined.
```

This requires an anchoring **prefix**, which is searched for by [this function](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexFCD.cs,5559c2458a83d8ee,references), whose comment says:

```
/*
 * This is the one of the only two functions that should be called from outside.
 * It takes a RegexTree and computes the set of chars that can start it.
 */
```

The matching algorithm contains code which returns a *no match* result immediately if the input string is shorter than the computed prefix.

Note that it's also looking for *anchors* and optimizing for these, of course.

I did not find a *minimum length* optimization in the code, but I admit I didn't read it thoroughly <sub>(gotta do that one day)</sub>. But I know other regex implementations which do this kind of optimization (PCRE comes to mind). Anyway, the .NET implementation has its own way of optimizing things, you should rely on that.