# Why regex does not care about string length

Tags: c#, regex, performance-testing

Why input length on regex does not affect performance and how is that possible?

The generated string is like this: 128 random characters. then two numbers inside parenthesis. and this is repeated many times.

```
128 radnom characters....(-2435346|45436) 128 radnom characters....(-32525562|-325346)
```

The regex gets all the numbers inside parenthesis. here is the pattern.

```
\(([-+]?\d+\|[-+]?\d+)\)
```

So the matches would be like

```
-2435346|45436
-32525562|-325346
etc...
```

Here is the code that does the benchmark. I start the stop watch after input is generated because i want to only evaluate Matching time.

```
Random rand = new Random();
Func<string> getRandString = // generates 128 random characters.
    () => Enumerable.Range(0, 128).Select(x => (char) rand.Next()).Aggregate("", (a, b) => a + b);
Func<int> getRandInteger = () => rand.Next(); // generates random number.
string format = "{0}({1}|{2})";

// Generate the big string.
StringBuilder bigstr = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // repeat 100 times.
{
    bigstr.Append(string.Format(format, getRandString(), getRandInteger(), getRandInteger()));
}
string input = bigstr.ToString();

Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\(([-+]?\d+\|[-+]?\d+)\)");
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed :\t{0}\nInputLength :\t{1}\nMatches Count :\t{2}", stopwatch.Elapsed, input.Length, matches.Count);
```

This is the output in my Console if I repeat loop `10` times.

```
Time Elapsed :   00:00:00.0004132
InputLength :    1500
Matches Count :  10
```

If I repeat loop `1000` times.

```
Time Elapsed :   00:00:00.0004373 // seriously?
InputLength :    149937
Matches Count :  1000
```

If I repeat loop `1000000` times.

```
Time Elapsed :   00:00:00.0004900 // wtf?
InputLength :    149964452
Matches Count :  1000000
```

Screenshot if you dont believe

[image]

Is this some kind of lazy evaluation? if so then how it can show the count of matches? how ever I did this under debugger and I could see the matches.

Is there something especial in my regex pattern that makes it fast? but how string length does not affect performance? I cant understand.

Comment: There is nothing special here.Your regex engine will travers the string and save all the states that matches with your regex, and you are benchmark on a 1000 time bigger string which is not a big deal for now adays machines.Just try much larger strings.Or maybe your benchmarikon is not fair.

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32618592/3764814) if you'd like to see some details about the string search algorithm used by the .NET regex engine.

Comment: Proper benchmarking: https://andreyakinshin.gitbooks.io/performancebookdotnet/content/science/microbenchmarking.html

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks. it was helpful. i now understand that under the debugger it shows part of results fast because only part of the string is evaluated.

Comment: By the way, drop `|` in the character class `[-|+]`, i.e. `[-+]`. Your current code allows `|` in front of the number. Also, there is no point in matching the second number lazily `\d+?`, just use `\d+`.

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks for mentioning that. Yes that was a mistake. I thought i should put OR in character class so i used `|`. I also dont know why i made it non greedy with `?`. Thats redundant of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the reasons this happens is that `matches.Count` property is evaluated *lazily*. When you stop your stopwatch, the matcher is prepared to do matching, but it has not found anything. Only when you call `matches.Count` does it start working, but you have stopped the timing by then.

A simple solution is to move `matches.Count` call into the portion of the code that you time.

Another reason is that you are including the time it takes to parse regex into account. This is a relatively expensive operation, so you should do it before turning on the stopwatch for better timing:

```
Regex testRegex = new Regex(@"\(([-+]?\d+\|[-+]?\d+)\)");
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var matches = testRegex.Matches(input);
var matchesCount = matches.Count;
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed :\t{0}\nInputLength :\t{1}\nMatches Count :\t{2}", stopwatch.Elapsed, input.Length, matchesCount);
```

Now the growth of time for 10 matches vs. 10,000 matches becomes considerable ([`00:00:00.0129844`](http://ideone.com/V51Tuq) vs. [`00:00:00.0843982`](http://ideone.com/RCbOjk)), though not as big as one might expect for a thousand-time difference in input length.

Comment: LOL, i thought the time it takes is actually for generating the string. what a stupid mistake! i also did this under debugger but i put break point after `Regex.Matches`. thanks anyway!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Here is [an implementation of `MatchCollection`](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Regex/System/Text/RegularExpressions/RegexMatchCollection@cs/1305376/RegexMatchCollection@cs). You can see from the code that the `GetMatch` method that does all the work is called lazily.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That link you provided does not work for me (the webpage is malformed and all the code is the same color as the background), [here is a link to the same method in the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexMatchCollection.cs.html#682620f47b442b05)