# Why don't regex engines ensure all required characters are in the string?

Tags: regex, string

For example, look at this email validating regex:
`^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$`. If you look carefully, there are three parts: stuff, the `@` character, and more stuff. So the regex requires an email address to have an `@`, thus the string `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!` will not match.

Yet most regex [engine](http://regexstorm.net/tester)s will catastrophically backtrack given this combination. (PCRE, which powers Regex101, is smarter than most, but other regex/string combinations can cause catastrophic backtracking.)

Without needing to know much about Big O, I can tell that combinatorial things are exponential, while searching is linear. So why don't regex engines ensure the string contains required characters (so they can quit early)?

Unfortunately, most of what I've read about catastrophic backtracking puts the blame on the regex writer for writing evil regexes, instead of exploring the possibility that regex engines/compilers need to do better. Although I found several [source](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5599.pdf)s that look at regex engines/compilers, they are too technical.

---

Coming back after getting more experience, I know that regexes are [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), meaning the execution plan is determined by the computer, not the programmer. Optimization is one of the ways that regex engines differ the most.

While PCRE and Perl have challenged the declarative status-quo with the introduction of backtracking control verbs, it is other engines, without the verbs, which are most likely to catastrophically backtrack.

Comment: In such cases `lazy` quantifier `?` and `*` comes into play. It's upon the author to use them wisely to make matching efficient. By default the regex are **`greedy`** and will check every combination.

Comment: If we take out the academic interest factor this may have: Maybe instead of requesting that whole regex engines be rewritten (because assuming from one rather specific case, that an easy(?) general solution to a complex problem (w|sh)ould exist, might be rather bold to begin with), the programmer, knowing about such problems already¹, should be the smart(er) one here, and do a check for strpos/indexof the `@` themselves first. (¹ That you should not even attempt to try and come up with a regex “solution” to validating email addresses, we assume they already know already, too ;)

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I know not to use regex for email validation (well, I probably would, but not with this one, and it would warn about, but pass through the "failures"), but I wanted to use a real-world  example.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're taking this the wrong way, really:

> Unfortunately, most of what I've read about catastrophic backtracking puts the blame on the regex writer for writing evil regexes, instead of exploring the possibility that regex engines/compilers need to do better. Although I found several sources that look at regex engines/compilers, they are too technical.

Well, if you write a regex, your regex engine will need to follow that program you've written.
If you write a complex program, then there's nothing the engine can do about that; this regex **explicitly** specifies that you'll need to match "stuff" first, before looking for the `@`.

Now, not being too involved in writing compilers, I agree, in this case, it might be possible to first identify all the "static" elements, which here are only said `@`, and look for them. Sadly, in the general case, this won't really help you, because there might either be more than one static element or the none at all…

If you cared about speed, you'd actually just first search for the `@` *with plain linear search*, and then do your regex thing after you've found one.

Regexes were never meant to be as fast as linear search engines, because they were rather meant to be much, much more powerful.

So, not only are you taking the wrong person to the judge (the regex engine rather than the regex, which is a program with a complexity), you're also blaming the victim for the crime (you want to harvest the speed of just looking for the `@` character, but still use a regex).

---

by the way, don't validate email addresses with regexes. It's the wrong tool: 
http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: _“because there might either be more than one static element or the none at all”_ – or even more complex situations, such as a `(a|b|cde|…)` … now, how much time would we want the regex engine to spend on analyzing and searching for such “static” stuff first (because it might(!) make the complete search/match easier in specific cases), before we let it get on with the work it is _designed_ to do.

Comment: The important piece of information in this answer is that *a regex is a program*. Besides, some regex engines do a couple optimizations. For instance, the .NET engine [performs a Boyer-Moore search](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32618592/3764814) when possible. PCRE has a "minimum required string length" approach. Other engines may do other tricks.

Comment: @CBroe one might argue that it might be possible to first compile the regex, test a few different implementations on a sample data set, compare performance, and use the right one. Then one would immediately realize that regexes were the wrong tool in the first place if performance is **that** critical.

Comment: Well I’d say there is a difference between “performance critical”, and the pits that real catastrophic backtracking can lead you into. Say the suggested email validation expression was used in a loop, to check 5k or so records (and that it does indeed backtrack _catastrophically_, by the usual definition of that term.) That is not a situation where you’d say the check was “performance critical” – but it can still surprise you, when that 5k loop doesn’t seem to want to a timely end, or busts time/memory limits …

Comment: So yeah, I agree, the programmer should do some performance measurements upfront, and maybe execute some “lighter” comparisons/checks first (and in most languages that perform &&-joined condition checks from left to right, that can quite easily be done) – offloading all responsibility on the regex engine here is a bit much.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Most of the time I am using regexes in Java, and you can compile them. In any case, I'm hardcoding the regex into the program and, in theory, it could be compiled at the same time as the rest of the code.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski In fact, the reason I am looking so much into the design of regex compilers/engines is because I know how much work other languages are optimized, like with pipeline prediction. I did look into what optimization exist already, a little, (although I think I visited the Boyer-Moore Wikipedia page on a prior, unrelated search).

Comment: @Laurel branch prediction is a CPU feature, and as such, regexes use it as well. By saying a regex is a program, what I mean is: if you write an *O(n²)* algorithm in any programming language, it won't be magically optimized by the compiler to a *O(log n)* algorithm (assuming such an algorithm exists). You write the algorithm, the compiler takes care of ensuring it'll get executed as-is, with some optimizations, but no big changes to its structure. Same goes for regexes.

Comment: I think that, conceptually, regexes are similar to SQL. In SQL, you tell it what you want, and it decides how it will get it (and holds most of the responsibility for performance). For regexes, the order of things in `|`s merely helps order the results so it returns the one at the top. In other languages, you are giving explicit directions, and if the computer does something wrong, it's usually because you told it to.

Comment: @Laurel not really. SQL is a declarative language, and you seem to think regexes are alike. DFA regexes are declarative, yes. But NFA regexes are not. They are clearly an imperative program. They may look declarative, but they are executed imperatively. Broadly speaking, these are technically not regexes anymore, they're more like CFG parsers.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski The only difference seems to be in what the definition of the correct match is.[(see here.)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Regular_expressions) Would it matter _how_ it works as long as the match is correct?

Comment: @Laurel once you get to hairy patterns, yes, it does matter. Think about things like Perl's `(*PRUNE)` etc. If you're interested in details, [read this](http://regex.info/book.html).